# Use a Java class file in Monodroid

Tags: c#, java, mono, xamarin.android

Is there a way to add a reference or use a Java class File in Monodroid?

Comment: [XY Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341)

Comment: I don't think it is off-topic. Xamarin.Android (MonoDroid), does allow for binding or wrapping up Java sources, however it is not the most user friendly experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to reference a `.class` file in a Xamarin.Android project. You can put the `.class` into a `.jar`:

```
jar cf Foo.jar path/to/The.class
```

Once you have a `.jar` file, you can add it to the project with a **Build action** of `AndroidJavaLibrary`.

Alternatively, you can create a Java Bindings Library Project and then add the `.jar`. This will allow generation of a C# wrapper over the Java type.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I have two questions. 1-where shall I execute this command to produce the jar file? 2-Is my question really off-topic??